# QFile class start of stram

Tags: qt, binaryfiles, qfile

I'm using Qt for reading binary file. I read file with `QFile` object, but sometimes I need to go back at begining of the file and read file again, but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`seek`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qiodevice.html#seek) function on your file :

```
file.seek(0);
```

If you are reading the file using a `QTextStream` you should use the `seek` function on the stream.